# Databinding textbox can't exit

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, textbox

I have the same issue as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217912/data-bound-textbox-cant-exit). It is caused bij a numeric nullable value of my dataset object. When the property of this object has an initial value of null, I can exit my textbox. When my textbox has a initial numeric value and clear the textbox, I cannot exit.

I want to be able to supply a null value by clearing the textbox. I know this is a validating issue, when setting the "CausesValidating" property to false, I can exit. Also my property setting function is never reached.

Any ideas or suggestions? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data-bound TextBox: can't exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217912/data-bound-textbox-cant-exit)

Comment: People are already voting to close this as an exact duplicate of the question you linked to. Can you explain how your problem is different, and why the answers to the other question *didn't* work in your case?

Comment: CausesValidation is set to true, because this how i want it (i need to check an integer range) - AutoValidate is set to EnablePreventFocusChange , which is correct on a real error. The last paragraph points to the right direction, but i should expect that the behaviour should always be the same. I now manually added Format and Parsing events to the Binding class, but I would not expect to do this for every nullable field. There must be an easy way?

Comment: I have the same problem. I understand the fix for inability to exit the text box, but I want to be able to set the data bound value back to NULL. It starts off as null, but then once it has a value it's like it can never go back (even though the database allows it).

Answer (score 4):

*(Sorry, at first I didn't see your reply asking for an easier way than manually attaching to the Format/Parse events, so my answer is probably not satisfying enough but for other people having the same problem, the code snippet might be useful.)*

You can use the Format and Parse event of the Binding of that TextBox to convert an empty string to DBNull.Value and back, so that the control is valid and you can leave it.

```
// Call AllowEmptyValueForTextbox() for each TextBox during initialization.

void AllowEmptyValueForTextBox(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (textBox.DataBindings["Text"] != null)
    {
        textBox.DataBindings["Text"].Format += OnTextBoxBindingFormat;
        textBox.DataBindings["Text"].Parse += OnTextBoxBindingParse;
    }
}

void OnTextBoxBindingParse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    // Convert the value from the textbox to a value in the dataset.
    string value = Convert.ToString(e.Value);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        e.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
}

void OnTextBoxBindingFormat(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    // Convert the value from the dataset to a value in the textbox.
    if (e.Value == DBNull.Value)
    {
        e.Value = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Instead of showing the user an empty textbox when the field in the dataset is empty, you can use the same mechanism to fill the textbox with a string like "(not set)" orso. In the Format method convert DBNull.Value to "(not set)" and in the Parse method convert it back.

See also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse